# How to color over a curve of a function

Tags: function, polygon, curve

Hi I need help to color a set of values. The conditions are:

1. y-1=0 <-> d=0
2. y <= ((1+x)/(1-x))^2 < 1
3. 1 < ((1+x)/(1-x))^2 <= y

I tried several times but in no way I had a good plot.
The last code I've tried is:

```
> x<-seq(-1,1,length=2201) 
> y<-((1+x)/(1-x))^2
> 
> plot(0,1, xlim = c(-0.6,0.6), ylim = c(-1,15)) 
> abline(h = 1,lty="dashed") 
> abline(v = 0,lty="dashed") 
> curve(((1+x)/(1-x))^2,add= TRUE,lty="dashed",from=-1,to=1)
> polygon(c(0,0,0.6,x[y>=1]),c(1,16,16,y[y>=1]),density=20,angle=45,border = NA)
```

I'm sorry for my bad english.
Thank you.